# intenting values individually form Listview row containing multiple values

Tags: android, json, android-intent, android-listview

I want to intent values separately from each listview row containing multiple values to another activity. And fetch each value in editext seperately in another activity:

My code is:

```
try
            {               
                JSONArray jArray =  new JSONArray(result);
                final ArrayList <String>arrayListTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                    {   
                        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                        JSONArray innerJsonArray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
                        JSONObject json_data = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);                          
                         at1=json_data.getString("title");
                         at= json_data.getString("mdate");
                         at2=json_data.getString("mtime");
                         at3=json_data.getString("venue");
                         at4=json_data.getString("organiser");
                         arrayListTitle.add(at1);
                         arrayListTitle.add(at);
                         arrayListTitle.add(at2);
                         arrayListTitle.add(at3);
                         s.append("\nTitle:"+at1);
                         s.append("\ndate:"+at);
                         s.append("\nTime:"+at2);
                         s.append("\nVenue:"+at3);
                         s.append("\nOrganiser:"+at4);  
                         s.append("\n");


                         r.add(s.toString());
                    }


                l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, r));
                l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) 
                    {
                      String selectedFromList =(String) (l.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));

                        // Starting new intent
                        intent1 = new Intent(RequestmeetActivity.this, ConfirmmeetActivity.class);


                        intent1.putExtra("title", arrayListTitle.get(myItemInt));
                        intent1.putExtra("mdate", arrayListTitle.get(myItemInt));
                        intent1.putExtra("mtime", arrayListTitle.get(myItemInt));
                        intent1.putExtra("venue", arrayListTitle.get(myItemInt));


                        startActivity(intent1); 
                    }                 
              });
            }
```

My activity looks like:

[image]

So i want to fetch value from this list view row individually and intent those value to another activity. How can i do that. Pls hlp me i am a newbie in android.. Thanks in advance.
On another activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){ 
      mtitle = extras.getString("title");
      stime = extras.getString("mtime");
      sdate = extras.getString("mdate");
      cvenue = extras.getString("venue");
    }

    title.setText(mtitle);
    cdate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    cdate.setText(sdate);
    venue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    venue.setText(cvenue);
    ctime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ctime.setText(stime);
```

Comment: create new arraylist for all that value like arrayListTitle. add value in that arraylist and get that value in onItemClick method arrayListTitle.get(myItemInt); and pass it to another activity by using intent put Extra.

Comment: How will i do that .. if u can show me some code for that actually im not getting of how to do it... @Maulik

Comment: _intent_ is not a verb: I do not understand your title and first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defind global ArrayList arrayListTitle = new ArrayList; as you define in r. and add value in it before append code in for loop. for the title arrayListTitle.add(at1);

```
ArrayList<String> arrayListTitle = new ArrayList<String>;

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {    
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            JSONArray innerJsonArray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
            JSONObject json_data = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            at1=json_data.getString("title");
            at= json_data.getString("mdate");
            at2=json_data.getString("mtime");
            at3=json_data.getString("venue");
            at4=json_data.getString("organiser");
            arrayListTitle.add(at1);  // check this line I have added value of title in arraylist you can take it same as data and time etc.
            s.append("\nTitle:"+at1);
            s.append("\ndate:"+at);
            s.append("\nTime:"+at2);
            s.append("\nVenue:"+at3);
            s.append("\nOrganiser:"+at4);   
            s.append("\n");
            r.add(s.toString());
        }
```

for listview item click:

```
 l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, 
                                   View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
        String selectedFromList =(String) (l.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
        // Starting new intent
        intent1 = new Intent(RequestmeetActivity.this, 
                                                    ConfirmmeetActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("title",arrayListTitle.get(myItemInt)); // check this line get value from the arraylistTitle for the particular position.
        intent1.putExtra("mdate",selectedFromList);
        intent1.putExtra("uid",uid);
        startActivity(intent1); 
    }
```

while getting the title in the another activity: write code like:

```
String title;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null){ 
  title = extras.getString("title"); // same for others
}

editTxt.setText(title);
```

Comment: Its giving error in this line:
 intent1.putExtra("title",arrayListTitle.get(myItemInt));
as: The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, Object)

Comment: check my edited answer. pass string arrayListTitle.get(position). have you put ArrayList<String> arrayListTitle = new ArrayList<String>;? print Log.e("title>>>",">>>"+arrayListTitle.get(myItemInt)); and tell me the value that you get is right or wrong?

Comment: Sorry Actually it is working for only first value for others its fetching the same value...

Comment: check your position it gives right or wrong? Please update your code what you have tried.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29190/discussion-between-priya89-and-maulik)

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of using android default list item layout(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1) use your own custom layout for List item.
- In that list item, you can separate each Fields as each text view.
- Then you can get each field fro your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you wish to send the data of the selected rows entire data to 2nd activity and edit the same.

To do this, you better create an simple custom adapter using arrayadapter as base class.

In your adapter's getView method set the Tag with your JSON Object and you can pass the entire json object to the second activity.

Simple adapter example is [here](http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/)